# RSpec undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test the following with RSpec and FactoryGirl:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
    it "assigns the requested dish to @dishes" do
        dish = create(:dish)
        get :show, id: dish
        expect(assigns(:dish)).to eq dish
    end
end
```

---

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dish, :class => 'Dish' do |f|
    f.name "TestDish"
    f.header "TestHeader"
    f.author_id "1"
    f.avatar { File.open("spec/support/sample_photo.jpg")}
  end

  factory :invalid_dish do |f|
    f.name nil
  end
end
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
  1) DishesController GET #show assigns the requested dish to @dishes
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: dish
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/dishes/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_dishes_show_html_erb___4424609358762382481_2199208220'
     # ./app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in show'
     # ./app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:15:in `show'
     # ./spec/controllers/dishes_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I believe the problems lies in my show view with this line:

`<p><%= @dish.author.full_name %></p>`

In the author.rb model I've defined the following:

```
def full_name
        full_name = first_name + " " + last_name
    end
```

my dish.rb model `belongs_to :author` and my author.rb model `has_many :dishes`

I've tried to google a bit around, but can't seem to find any specific answer to my issue, apart from this thread [RSpec: ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450508/rspec-actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-full-name-for-nilnilclas) but I don't really understand what's going on there.

Let me know if any more info is needed!

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `undefined method 'full_name' for nil:NilClass` error because in `@dish.author.full_name`, `@dish.author` is **nil** i.e., the dish record doesn't have a matching author record.

What you need is to setup the factories such that when you create a dish its associated record also gets created :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dish, :class => 'Dish' do |f|
    f.name "TestDish"
    f.header "TestHeader"
    f.avatar { File.open("spec/support/sample_photo.jpg")}
    ## f.author_id "1"  Remove this line
    association :author, factory: :assoc_author  ## set association
  end

  factory :assoc_author, :class => 'Author' do |f|
    ## assign fields
    f.first_name "John"
    f.last_name "Doe" 
  end
  ## ...
end
```

This way when you call `create(:dish)`, it will create a record in `dishes` table plus an associated record in `authors` table.

Comment: Is it possible for me to configure my test so that a dish has a matching author then?

Comment: That makes total sense... But now I get a: ``method_missing': Factory already registered: author`` error. Presumably because I've already got an author.rb factory?

Comment: Yes..thats correct. See my update again. I changed the factory name so it doesn't conflict with the existing.

Comment: Or you could use the existing factory. And don't include this new one. Just make sure to set the association(with correct existing factory name) in `factory :dish`.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't fix it. It still returns the same error. Does it have something to do with the relations maybe?

Comment: Probably, how is Dish related to an Author?

Comment: Also, did you remove `f.author_id "1"` from factory :dish

Comment: I'm sorry @Kirti, but I'm a complete novice when it comes to rails, so you would have to expand on how to do that. (include the existing factory)

Comment: A dish ``belongs_to :author`` and an author ``has_many :dishes``

Comment: Follow my code exactly. Copy BOTH factory :dish and factory :assoc_author. Notice that I removed `f.author_id "1"` from factory :dish

Comment: I tried following you exact instruction, but to no avail I'm afraid. It gives me the following error ``undefined method 'assoc_author=' `` If I try and add : in front of assoc_author (in the :dish factory) It comes back an gives me following error: ``Validation failed: Author  must be specified`` (since I've required the presence of an author in my model)

Comment: See the updated answer. I have changed the association in `factory :dish` as `association :author, factory: :assoc_author  `